# Padding and show only the last N characters of a masked/password/secret variable's value

Tags: bash, passwords, padding, masking, secret-key

I want to prompt a user to enter a secret value (for ex: password variable, credit card, some key/token) and would like to see if there's a way to show the last N (lets say 4 characters) of that variable's value.

Ex:
Enter your credit card# : 1234567898765432

I can use wrappers for ex `stty -echo/echo` to hide what user will enter or use `read -s variable` and it'll hide the values but what I'd like is to show only last N (for ex: 4) characters of this variable i.e.
if I say `$ echo $mySecretVariable` (not sure if I really have to write a function) then it will echo the value as: `************5432` or your token key value last 4 ends with `*******************C5fx` something like that where all the characters will be padded with a `*` and only the last N will be shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this bash function for masking all but last 4 characters:

```
mask() {
   local r="${1?needs an argument}"
   if ((${#r} > 4)); then
      r="${r:0: -4}"
      echo "${r//?/*}${1: -4}"
   else
      echo "$r"
   fi
}
```

Then use it as:

```
mask 1234567898765432
************5432

mask 123
123

mask 123456
**3456
```

Comment: I wonder why you got 430k hits, thanks :) I guess the only way is to do via a function then.